# Two clocks along different worldlines

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time

I have been reading and watching videos about this subject for a while now.  I just can not seem to grasp the idea.  Let's say we have two clocks.  I leave one at home and keep one in my pocket. Then, I started running at speed that is close to speed of light to my school then come back to my house.  If I compare those two clocks how would they differ in time?

Answer (score 1):

The world lines of both clocks pass through two particular events ('points' in spacetime), the event of your leaving the home and the event of your returning.

The worldline of the clock at home is *straight* while the worldline of the clock in your pocket must be *curved* due to the acceleration you undergo during your near light speed trip out and back.

A result in special relativity is that the elapsed time is *longest* along the straight (inertial) worldline; *all other worldlines have less elapsed time*.

According to the Wikipedia article "[Proper time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_time)":

> In relativity, proper time is the elapsed time between two events as
>   measured by a clock that passes through both events. The proper time
>   depends not only on the events but also on the motion of the clock
>   between the events. **An accelerated clock will measure a smaller
>   elapsed time between two events than that measured by a
>   non-accelerated (inertial) clock between the same two events.** The twin
>   paradox is an example of this effect.

Thus, the clock in your pocket will show less elapsed time that the clock at home.

Comment: Thanks for your simplified answer!  All these answers are great!  They are just a bit hard to understand.  If the clock in my pocket shows less time has elapsed, does this indicate that I traveled through time?

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say we have two clocks.

Let's call the (coordinate) times of these two clocks $t_A$, and $t_B$, respectively.

> I leave one at home and keep one in my pocket. Then, I started running [...] then come back to my house. If I compare those two clocks how would they differ in time?

If it is also given (corresponding to the comment by the OP above: "*they increased at same rate*") that each of these two clocks had been "good" (i.e. "running at a definite, constant rate") during the separation , i.e.

$\frac{d}{d \tau_A}[t_A] = \frac{d}{d \tau_B}[t_B] \text{=(abbreviated as)=} \text{rate}$

then the "*difference in time*" between these two clocks, at the return, is

$t_A[ \text{at return to B} ] - t_B[ \text{at return to A} ] :=$

$t_A[ \text{at separation from B} ] - t_B[ \text{at separation from A} ] +$
$\text{rate} * \Delta\tau_A[ \text{from separation from B, until return to B} ] * $     $\left(1 - \frac{\Delta\tau_B[ \text{from separation from A, until return to A} ] }{ \Delta\tau_A[ \text{from separation from B, until return to B} ] } \right) =$

$t_A[ \text{at separation from B} ] - t_B[ \text{at separation from A} ] +$
$\left( t_A[ \text{at return to B} ] - t_A[ \text{at separation from B} ] \right) * $
$\left(1 - \frac{\Delta\tau_B[ \text{from separation from A, until return to A} ] }{ \Delta\tau_A[ \text{from separation from B, until return to B} ] } \right),$

where $\Delta\tau_A$ is the duration (a.k.a. "proper time") of one clock, and $\Delta\tau_B$ the duration of the other, respectively, between their indications as specified.

If it is also given (corresponding to the comment by the OP above: "*[...] started out at same time*") that

$t_A[ \text{at separation from B} ] = t_B[ \text{at separation from A} ],$

then this "*difference in time*" between these two clocks, at the return, simplifies to

$t_A[ \text{at return to B} ] - t_B[ \text{at return to A} ] =$

$\left( t_A[ \text{at return to B} ] - t_A[ \text{at separation from B} ] \right) * $
$\left(1 - \frac{\Delta\tau_B[ \text{from separation from A, until return to A} ] }{ \Delta\tau_A[ \text{from separation from B, until return to B} ] } \right).$

Finally, in order to evaluate the number

$\frac{\Delta\tau_B[ \text{from separation from A, until return to A} ] }{ \Delta\tau_A[ \text{from separation from B, until return to B} ] }$

it would of course be necessary to measure (or to assume) the geometric-kinematic relations between these two clocks during their being separated from each other more specificly. (It might for instance be relevant which, if any, of these two clocks had remained a member of an intertial system throughout the separation; at least within some suitable accuracy.)

Answer (score 0):

Without getting to mathy, the reason is because you are dilating time and what you would see is that the clock at home was much ahead of your clock you held when you ran near the speed of light. In other words, you would be in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's say you have a friend staying at home measuring the time and observing you with a telescope - the whole situation will be described from his point of view. Namely, we will use his measure of distance $x$ and the time $t$ he measures with the stopwatch in his hand.

Special relativity tells us that he has a means of calculating your "proper time", i.e. the time that runs on the stopwatch in your pocket while running, from observing your velocity. The first statement is trivial: "the total proper time is the sum of the proper times during each phase of motion. This is formally written as:
$$\tau_{1,2} = \sum_{\dots} \Delta \tau = \int_1^2 d \tau$$
Where the second relation describes the situation when you continuously change your velocity so that every infinitesimal piece of your time changes it's rate towards your friend at home and the sum has to be done through an integral. The trick is now to find out the rate of change of your proper time $ \tau$ with respect to the home time $t$. Relativity tells us that for a fixed running velocity $v$ we have
$$\Delta \tau = \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \Delta t\,\to\,d \tau = \sqrt{1-v(t)^2/c^2} d t $$
Hence, the only thing to find out how much time the stopwatch in your pocket will measure is to compute the following
$$\tau_{1,2} = \int_1^2 \sqrt{1-v(t)^2/c^2} d t$$
But this is highly nontrivial for reasonable velocity histories $v(t)$, so I am going to use a *model* for a *qualitative* understanding.

Why a model? Because the description will contain infinite accelerations, where we would have to include general-relativistic effects for consistency, because horrible energy transfers would be happening. Thus this description gives us a qualitative understanding of the resulting time-difference only, and should be understood as a very rough approximation to a process with small accelerations (smoothed out slowing down etc.).

Ok, so you start at rest at home - $v=0,x=0$. From $t_1$ to $t_1 + (t_1-t_2)/2$ you are moving with a velocity $0.5 c$ and from $t_1 + (t_1-t_2)/2$ you move with a velocity $-0.5 c$ until $t_2$ when you arrive home again and stop to compare your times. Your proper running time will be
$$\tau_{1,2} = \sqrt{1 - (0.5 c)^2/c^2}(t_1-t_2)/2 + \sqrt{1 - (-0.5 c)^2/c^2}(t_1-t_2)/2 = \sqrt{0.75} (t_1 - t_2)$$
That is, to you, your stopwatch would show $0.87$ times less runtime than the stopwatch left at home. But since relativity is relative and does not discriminate, how is it decided that you are the one who has a shorter time? *Because you are the one who starts and stops*. That is, you go back into the home frame of reference to compare your times, so the home frame of reference is suddenly "privileged".

Remember that this description is highly unrealistic, but a realistic descriptions *always* lead to shorter time of the "runner" and longer time of the "home" at least until you are in a complicated gravitational situation. An experiment has actually shown this effect, the [Hafele-Keating experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment).

---

Gravitation? - We can neglect it as long as you move strictly at the same altitude $\to$ same gravitational potential and acceleration. There would be some technical complications with moving around a considerable part of the Earth because it's spherical shape would require a change in our description, but no new qualitative effects would appear.

However, if for a considerable time you would move with a speed smaller than the Earth's rotation and orbit, you would actually gain a time difference not from your movement with respect to the Earth's surface but from a smaller or larger speed with respect to the "background space". You can see in the already linked Hafele-Keating experiment that in that case the relative speeds were so small that the westward motion *prolonged* the time of the "runner" clock with respect to the "home". The intuitive reason is that the westward clock was actually counter-rotating against the faster Earth rotation and thus moving slower. But a non hand-waivy description would require general relativity.

Comment: Void: "_a friend staying at home measuring the time and observing you [...] his measure of distance $x$_" -- Distance of that "_friend staying at home_" with respect to **whom**? (Do you claim that the geometric and/or kinematic relation of "_a friend staying at home_" and some specific "travelling protagonist" could be characterized in terms of a "_measure of distance $x$_"? Or are there additional participants involved which you haven't named explicitly yet?) [to be continued]

Comment: Void: "_Ok, so you start [...] when you arrive home again [...] compare your times. Your proper running time_" -- ... a.k.a. "your duration (from start indication until arrival indication)" ... -- "_will be [...]_ $\sqrt{0.75} ~ (t_2 - t_1)$" -- Rather: $\sqrt{0.75} \simeq 0.87$ of the duration of the stay-at-home friend from his indication of your departure until his indication of your return. "_your stopwatch would show $0.87$ times less runtime than the stopwatch left at home._" -- What should the durations have to do with what these stopwatches "_show_"?? Are they supposed to be **good**??

Comment: @user12262 The friend at home has established a coordinate system with respect to himself by sending signals to landmarks he has observed as static and measuring the time delay of the returning signal. He has also put clocks on the landmarks also synchronized by light-signals from home. That is, saying "you are at $x=x_0$ at $t=t_0$" means "the friend at home saw you near a landmark with a label $x_0$ with a clock attached to it saying it's $t_0$". I.e. if someone else measured the distance, the result might be different, so I say we use his established measure of distance.

Comment: @user12262 Well, stopwatches have a display which shows duration elapsed between certain events. I talk about stopwatches, because physics should talk about things that can be measured and the statement is that "$0.87$ times less physics has happened" in the runners frame of reference. That is, any kind of physical watch based on a physical principle will show less time elapsed when in the runners pocket.

Comment: Void: "_[...] landmarks [...]_" -- Ah, right: landmarks. (Or by MTW's terminology of Box 13.1: "principal identifiable points".) Surely landmarks such as "_the friend's home_"; or even that friend him/her/itself; or even "the traveller", too. "_sending signals to landmarks he has observed as static and measuring the time delay of the returning signal._" -- How should be defined/determined which landmarks had been (mutually?) "_observed as static_", or not? By measuring whether the (mutual) "_time delays_" (a.k.a. "ping durations") had been constant, or not? [comment parts 2 and 3 to follow]

Comment: Void: "_The friend at home has established a coordinate system wrt. himself [...]_" -- Why sprinkle any coordinate tuples on the setup at all?! Surely the (suitable) friend and suitable "(mutually _static_)" landmarks may determine (from the ratios of their mutual ping duations) ratios of their "distances" between each other; and surely the (magnitude of the) quantity $v$ of your answer represents **speed**, not just some "coordinate speed"?  "_[...] if someone else measured the distance, the result might be different_" -- ?? Is "distance" not a **proper** attribute of suitable two landmarks?

Comment: Void: "_stopwatches have a display which shows duration elapsed between certain events._" -- [Stopwatches I know about](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopwatch) have displays indicating **numbers**. (ints, rationals,...) What do you propose those numbers might have to do with durations (of that stopwatch, between indication pairs)? And: do you suppose this was specified by the OP question?? "_any kind of physical watch based on a physical principle will show less time elapsed when in the runners pocket._" -- No: only **clock pairs of equal proper rates**. So: how to compare in the first place?.

Comment: @user12262 Is there something you want to actually clarify or are you trying to pull off a "Dumb-Socrates" dialogue on me? Do you have a specific question which you could not answer yourself?

Comment: Void: "_Is there something you want to actually clarify [...]_" -- Yes, of course, namely: Whether questions which occur to me in consideration of your answer (in its present version) and your subsequent responses would lead you to reconsider and rework your answer to the OP question; and how. This could obviously only be answered by you yourself.

Comment: @user12262 ok, wow. Not going to really comment on that. Your last comment says more than enough already. But if you aren't going to be practically clear and instead insist on only being technically clear when raising issues with a post, then the only affect of such comments you should expect is frustration of the poster. With that in mind, your apparent reluctance to appeal succinctly to your co-conversant's expected level of formality or indeed technically betrays nothing but self-sustaining superiority and, only after several occurrences, becomes offensive.

Comment: @Jim: "_[...] reluctance to appeal succinctly to your co-conversant's expected level of formality_" -- I strive to be as "_formal_" as I can reasonably muster, because public archived correspondence is not just addressing the incidental co-conversant(s) but posterity; and less "_formal_" terminology may be established, if desirable. "_[...] becomes offensive._" -- I consider it my courtesy (even obligation, as a physicst) that **I do ask** for "_formal_" underpinnings of incidental terminology. That seems less offensive than presuming outright that co-conversants were "not even wrong".

Comment: @user12262 I think you misinterpreted me. By "expected level of formality" I did not mean to imply you are not "formal" enough. In fact, it was my intent to imply that you were being too "formal" and to explain that, while unfaultable and appreciated initially, this leads to frustrating or antagonizing your co-conversant if continued after they repeatedly request (or display appreciative tendencies toward) a shift to lesser "formality".

Comment: So my "[...] becomes offensive" was not a criticism, but a warning, as I read through the conversation you were having and noticed (intentional or not) that you were continuing apace at your initial level of speech after several subtextual requests to "tone it down". It was my intent to make you aware of this before others interpreted the reluctance to "tone it down" as hostile, aloof, or generally offensive (as *I'm sure* that was not your intent)

Comment: @Jim: "_think you misinterpreted me. [...] you were being too "formal"_" -- Not to worry: I think this was exactly the interpretation based on which I wrote my preceding comment. (The word "_too_" being perfectly unambiguous; and I'm not quite sure about what you meant by "_formal_". But I like to believe it refers especially to the catch phrase in our other correspondence above following the OP question.) p.s. Apologies for "cluttering Void's and/or user41616's comment space": If only there were some other more appropriate **public** and **archived** venue on PSE ... [to be continued]

Comment: @Jim: "_you were continuing apace at your initial level of speech after several subtextual requests to "tone it down"._" -- "_Subtext_" seems kinda hard to quantify; but I certainly wouldn't disagree with your assessment. Now: What about my untiring subtextual requests to "tone it <expletive_conciliatorily_suppressed> **up**" ?!? ... "_[...] a warning_" -- Yeah, thanks. (I had looked up ["things _Socratic_"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic), and not for the first time, after user Void's latest comment. &)

Answer (score -2):

Technically they wouldn't differ in time because to come back to your house you would have to decelerate and accelerate, which is under the realms of general relativity **or as seen in comments below (thanks to @dgh) we can use comoving frames. You could use two frames one moving towards school and one away from school and Lorentz transform between the two, or you could use an infinite number of comoving frames in both directions and use the infinitesimal Lorentz transformations between each of the frames, hence integrate them to get total transformation**. However, in *simple* special relativity your clock would be at say 2 mins past 12 and the clock at home would be at 30 mins past 12.This is because when you travel "fast" (relative to some observer) your time slows down even though you wouldn't notice it. What you would notice is that the distance you travel is decreased by

$$L=L_{0}\sqrt{1-\left(\tfrac{v}{c}\right)^2}$$

Where $L$ is the distance you would see, and $L_{0}$ is the distance your mom (waiting for you at home) would see you travel. This is similar to the Twins paradox which you can learn about here http://www.phys.unsw.edu.au/einsteinlight/jw/module4_twin_paradox.htm

or you can google twin paradox.

You can find how much the time differs by using time dilation equation (or Lorentz transformations):

$$\Delta t=\frac{\Delta t_{0}}{\sqrt{1-\left(\tfrac{v}{c}\right)^2}}$$

Where $\Delta t$ is the time elapsed for the clock in your pocket and $\Delta t_{0}$ is the "stationary" clock left at home.

Comment: ...and one of the most important insights in special relativity is that **you might as well say that the other person's clock slowed down**, if you take the point of view where you stood still. Time is relative, not absolute.

Comment: Special relativity can handle accelerated motion in flat space-time just fine using momentarily comoving inertial reference frames. General relativity is not needed at all.

Comment: @dgh Yes this is true. And you would get that the times do not differ as I said above (resolution of twin paradox). But wouldn't this approach require an instantaneous change of velocity from going towards school to going back home (not very realistic) or an infinite amount of comoving inertial frames? That's why I didn't mention it in my answer but I would not mind editing it

Comment: @jerk_dadt, yes, for realistic (non-instantaneous) acceleration the formalism uses an infinite number of co-moving reference frames in succession. It's done using elementary calculus: adding together the effect of infinitely many infinitesimally small contributions is exactly what an integral of a single variable is. Accelerated trajectories are very standard fair in special relativity.

Comment: @dgh Ok, thanks. I forgot what an integral was. I mentioned your comment in my answer. Thanks!